# F1 score in a multi-label classification where the number of labels in one image is sparse and the number of labels between classes is biased

Tags: scikit-learn, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

I use scikit-learn to measure multi-label classification with f-score where labels are imbalanced per image and the number of labels  is low per image.

What should I use and why? `average = "micro"` or `"samples"`?

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if you have biased or unbiased data, the `average='micro'` or `average='macro'` is considered as the better as it gives you "better" results. You can refer [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/micro-average-vs-macro-average-performance-in-a-multiclass-classification-settin) to know why macro is considered as good.

Comment: It's imbalance, not biased. My mistake.When I use scikit_learn to measure multi-label classification of coarse labeled images with unbalanced labels per sample using f1score, should I use average="micro" or "samples"?

Comment: Biased or imbalanced is the same thing where you don't have the almost equal ratio of classes.  I suggest you should go with the either `weighted` or `macro`.